# deep linking to tab in teams from adaptive card from bot

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, deep-linking

Given we have a teams bot and personal teams tab ( with name TT and content URL : `a.example.com/g` ).

Consider a scenario, Bot sent an adaptive card with openUrl button (whose url is `a.example.com/b/c?d=f`). On clicking this, normally the url `a.example.com/b/c?d=f` will be opened in new browser tab.

Since this above URL can be opened in  teams tab TT, I am planning to deeplink to the tab and open the url in the tab.

On using openUrl button's url as `https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/<appId>/<entityId>`, ( referred from [Generate a deep link to your tab](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links#generate-a-deep-link-to-your-tab) ), I was able to achieve redirection to the expected teams tab TT. But it doesn't solve my entire problem, because I should be opening the `a.example.com/b/c?d=f` in the tab, not its default content URL.

How can I achieve redirection from Chat tab to personal teams tab and open the url `a.example.com/b/c?d=f` in the tab automatically.

Comment: Your question isn't really clear. Are you wanting to go to the url from -within- your tab?

Comment: @Vishwam - Could you please elaborate and share the repro steps, so that we can analyze it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `subEntityId` property in the deeplink for this. Put a URL-encoded value of the url to be passed to your tab, and decode it from within the tab (there's a section in the doc you linked about accessing the value from your tab via the Context object: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links#consume-a-deep-link-from-a-tab)

Comment: In case of browser teams, teams desktop client, android teams app the approach you mentioned is working fine. 
But in case of teams iOS app, I am unable to access the expected subEntityId. Any idea why this is behaving in this way.?

Comment: No, no idea - it might be a platform specific bug. List it as a new question so the Microsoft team members can see it properly on this site and investigate further